# How do i fix it in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

Hello i am trying to write a method that checks whether a
string is a valid password. I Suppose the password rules are as
follows:
A password must have at least ten characters.
A password consists of only letters and digits.
A password must contain at least three digits.

I wrote the code but i see this error i don't know why.

```
package javaapplication6;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;



public class JavaApplication6 {
public static boolean isvalidPassword(String nume){
      int count = 0;
      for(int i=0; i<nume.length();i++){
         if(Character.isDigit(nume.charAt(i))){
             count++;
     
         }
         
     }
     if (count<3){
         return false;
     } 
    
    
     if (nume.length()<10){
     return false;
    }
  
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nume.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(nume.charAt(i)charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(nume.charAt(i))){
             return false; }
          }
 return true;}


    
   }
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code as text in your question, not as images.

Comment: Sorry i am new in stackoverflow i will fix it

Comment: What error/exception do you get? Please put the entire stack trace into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the line

```
if (!Character.isLetter(nume.charAt(i)charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(nume.charAt(i))){
```

you see, that `charAt(i)` is duplicate:

```
nume.charAt(i)charAt(i)
```

Remove one of the method calls and you should be fine.